# udev rules ignore_device

Tags: linux, fedora, udev

I'm on Fedora 18. In `/etc/udev/rules.d`, I've added new rule (`70-stm32.rules`) with following content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="STM32_STLink", OPTIONS=="ignore_device"
```

Then restarted udev:

```
systemctl restart systemd-udevd.service
```

But device still seem to be recognized and mounted as USB drive.

Where is my mistake?

I want to ignore following device

```
udevadm info /dev/sdb
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/block/sdb
N: sdb
S: disk/by-id/usb-STM32_STM32_STLink-0:0
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
S: disk/by-uuid/A8D9-2F05
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-STM32_STM32_STLink-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 /dev/disk/by-uuid/A8D9-2F05
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sdb
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/block/sdb
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FS_TYPE=vfat
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: ID_FS_UUID=A8D9-2F05
E: ID_FS_UUID_ENC=A8D9-2F05
E: ID_FS_VERSION=FAT16
E: ID_INSTANCE=0:0
E: ID_MODEL=STM32_STLink
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=STM32\x20STLink
E: ID_MODEL_ID=3744
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_3_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=STM32_STM32_STLink-0:0
E: ID_TYPE=disk
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=STM32
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=STM32\x20\x20\x20
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0483
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=16
E: MPATH_SBIN_PATH=/sbin
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=33484404
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you are using a match key operator, i.e. `==` instead of an assign key operator: `=`.
Second, it's not an OPTION but an ENVIRONMENT variable: `ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}`. Also, I'd use a higher number like `98-stm32.rules` so as to prevent other rules overriding it.
That being said, the following rule should work (it does on my system):

```
ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="STM32_STM32_STLink-0:0", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

run:

```
udevadm control --reload
```

to reload rules.

Answer (score 8):

#### `ignore_device`

`ignore_device` (udev) was removed with udev release 148. See [release note](https://lwn.net/Articles/364728/) or [changelog](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/hotplug/udev.git/tree/ChangeLog?id=HEAD)

If you noticed, all topics suggesting the use of it are old (~ 2009).

#### Alternative solution: udisks (part of freedesktop project)

A quick alternative is to use: `ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"` for distribution with `udisks`,  `ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"` for distributions which include `udisks2`.

**Reference:** [Archlinux Wiki: Udisks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks)

#### Another possible solution: SYSFS (from Linux).

Either `device/authorized` , `device/remove` or `driver/unbind`, any of these may prevent OS from using the device.